# I want to create a load test scenario with 12 users where only one is performing the action while rest are just watching

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

Scenario --> There is a total of 12 users. Among them is one admin user that will create a meeting. After the meeting is created the other 11 users will also join the meeting. Now the admin user will add content to the meeting like adding tasks and attaching notes, while the other 11 users will view the activity that the admin is performing. Is it possible to create a load test script in JMeter for the above scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally people use different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) in order to implement different groups of business users.

So if you add

- 1 Thread Group with 1 user which creates the meeting, adding tasks, attaching notes
- 1 Thread Group with 11 users which passively participating: being online, receiving updates, etc.

it should do the trick for you.

If you prefer to stay with 1 Thread Group there are following options:

1. [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller) where you can conditionally execute this or that sampler basing on i.e. current thread (virtual user) number
2. [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller) which chooses which child to run basing on a "switch" value
3. [Weighted Switch Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/weighted-switch-controller-jmeter) which provides easy handy visual way for defining the desired child samplers execution percentage

Comment: On using the two-thread group approach, how can I make sure that users in the second-thread group will wait until the meeting is created by users in the first-thread group?@Dmitri T

Comment: The easiest option is using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-ten-jmeter-plugins#comm)